# OpenSuSE: useradd: user not active

Tags: opensuse

If I add uses to old SuSE versions (11.3, 11.4) useradd creates users which are not active. I need to use yast to active the new user.

Is there a way to do this in a script? (Not interactive with yast)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

SuSE 11.3 and 11.4 need a password for useradd. Otherwise the new user is not active.

At least with SuSE 12.3 no password is allowed. The user has no password, he must use ssh public key auth or an other way (that's what I want).